# Cannot uninstall extension gnome shell extension

Tags: gnome, uninstall, gnome-shell, gnome-shell-extension

I have Ubuntu 17.10, with GNOME Shell, and I have installed [this](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/602/window-list/) extension.
Now I am unable to turn it off or uninstall it.

I have tried to uninstall it from the extensions.gnome.org website (Installed 
Extensions -> clicking on the red cross), the extension is still there.

I have tried to remove `$HOME/.local/share/gnome-shell/extensions/windowList` and restarting (open the run dialog with Alt+F2, and enter restart), the extension is still there.

How can I remove it?

Comment: As you can see from https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/602/window-list/ , it seems to be a general problem with 17.10

Answer (score 1):

I have found the way

```
sudo rm -R /usr/share/gnome-shell/extensions/window-list@gnome-shell-extensions.gcampax.github.com/
```

For some reason it gets installed system-wide